# Sitecore data API, LINQ and language versions

Tags: linq, sitecore

We have a multi-language Sitecore installation and have discovered a small issue when using LINQ queries off of a Sitecore item. The issue is that it seems to ignore the context language / item language versions in the LINQ query (ie. it returns items that don't have a language version matching the current context language).

Here are two LINQ queries; neither of which work as expected:

```
        var items = item.Children.Where(i => i.TemplateName == "Brochure")
                    .ToList();

        var items = item.Children.Where(i => i.TemplateName == "Brochure" && i.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language)
                    .ToList();
```

If I change the statement to use Axes and a Sitecore query, it works as expected and items do not return if they do not have the appropriate language version:

```
        var items = (item.Axes.SelectItems("./*[@@templatekey='Brochure']") ?? Enumerable.Empty<Item>())
                    .ToList();
```

Has anyone got around this using LINQ, or would it be best to convert everything to Sitecore queries for statements like these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items have versions and versions exist for a specific language.
The item itself exists without a language.

If you only want the items that have a version in the context language, you need to check if it has versions:

```
var items = item.Children
    .Where(i => i.TemplateName == "Brochure")
    .Where(i => i.Versions.Count > 0)
    .ToList();
```